# Predefined function for textarea character counting

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

I know it's pretty simple to write this function in javascript, but for a class I'm taking, I'm supposed to reference a predefined method to limit the number of characters that can be entered into a textarea and was unsuccessful in my search.  Does anyone know of one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't get exactly what you're looking for, but

```
document.getElementById("textareaId").value.length
```